# Test Class, File Name

Tags: drjava

I wrote my code already and wrote a test class in Dr. Java. But how do I save this to have it compile and run. I keep getting " class TestGradeDistribution is public, should be declared in a file named TestGradeDistribution.java" but I have the file name as GradeDistribution already. Help!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the class name and the name of the `.java` file have to match exactly.

If you've copied GradeDistribution and made it into a class called TestGradeDistribution, you have to save it as `TestGradeDistribution.java`. Otherwise, the Java compiler won't be able to recognize it.

Best of luck.